# Garbage characters in C

Tags: c++, c, string, special-characters, newline

## Edited question

I understood my mistake in the code I had given in the original question, and the characters I was getting are garbage characters. Although, I still have a few questions about garbage characters in C:

- Why can't the character [image] be copied?
- Do garbage characters have some pattern? Meaning that can you predict for an empty string what character can come, for an empty integer what will come, and so on.
- When a variable is declared, why does it have a garbage character instead of being blank? Is there a specific reason of storing it with a garbage character?
- For a string which is not null-terminated, will the same garbage character be printed on every OS? If yes, which one?
- Are there the same garbage characters on every OS? Or are they different?
- Is there a way to print these characters on the `stdout` buffer in C / C++?
- If you see carefully in the character [image], there are some characters and numbers in it. Do they represent something?
- Is there a list of garbage characters which can be printed in C / C++?

---

---

## Original Question

> **Title of original question:** Mysterious character output in C

I had come across this code in K & R:

```
int scanline (char str [], int lim)                                                     /* Line will be read in 'str []', while lim is the maximum characters to be read */
{
    int c, len, j;                                                                      /* 'len' will have the length of the read string */

    j = 0;                                                                              /* Initializing 'j' */
    for (len = 0; (c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++len)                          /* Reading a character one by one, till the user enters '\n', and checking for failure of 'getchar' */
    {
        if (len < (lim -2))                                                             /* Checking that string entered has not gone beyond it's boundaries. '-2' for '\n' and '\0' */
        {
           str [j] = c;                                                                 /* Copying read character into 'string [j]' */
           ++ j;                                                                        /* Incrementing 'j' by 1 */
        }
    }
    if (c == '\n')                                                                      /* Checking if user has finished inputting the line */
    {
        str [j] = c;                                                                    /* Copying newline into string */
        ++j;
        ++ len;
    }

    return len;                                                                         /* Returning number of characters read */
}
```

In the K & R, it is known as `getline`, but I made changes, added comments, and thus defined it as `scanline`. To test this, I made a demo program:

```
#include <mocl/cancel.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int len;
    char str [50];
    len = scanline (str, 50);
    printf ("len = %d\n str = %s\n", len, str);
    return 0;
}
```

The required headers and the function was in my own library, `cancel.h`. Then when I compiled my program, it was successful. Although, when I ran the executable, I got unexpected output (I cannot type it as I get a character which when I copy, it just gets pasted as 'm'):

[image]

The mysterious character is [image] which when I copy, gets copied as the letter `m`. Also, when I run my program with different inputs, I get different mysterious outputs:

[image]

In another case, I get perfect output, just that a blank line is printed:

[image]

I had also come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651800/what-is-this-mysterious-output-in-c) question, in which the user gets the same symbol.

---

***What have I done till now?***

I searched a lot, and I could not find any clue about [image] this character, but if you see carefully, in the second image, I get more characters when I enter "hi this is ashish". One of them is the slash, and one is [image]. But I get another character [image]. I got [this](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_control_codes_and_extended_characters_from_a_string#C) link which was showed how to reproduce it, and explained it, although I could not understand. When you run the code given there, you get a lot of characters, and one of them is [image]. Although, even the author of that article could not copy it, and has not posted it. So here's the output:

[image]

That was the actual output, as that's not clear, here's a cut out version:

[image]

So basically I got to know that both the characters [image] and [image] are extended characters from a string. At that point, I actually figured out what was causing the problem in `scanline`.

The lines

```
if (c == '\n')                                                                      /* Checking if user has finished inputting the line */
{
    str [j] = c;                                                                    /* Copying newline into string */
     ++j;
     ++ len;
}
```

were causing the problems as you were copying a newline into the string. It worked, but I'm not sure why, as doing that was just a guess. I searched but still could not find the reason.

---

***My Questions***

- How does removing those lines make the program work properly?
- What are the characters [image] and [image]? What are they supposed to do and how did they appear over here?
- Are there any more characters like this?
- Why can't those characters be copied?
- Is it Undefined Behavior?

Comment: `str` is not null-terminate.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? I would like to improve my post.

Comment: Some toolsets will make DEBUG builds and fill memory that otherwise wouldn't be filled (because your code doesn't say to) so that you and its debug libraries can easily catch _some_ mistakes while testing _some_ execution paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some confusion here regarding the term **garbage characters**.  What it refers to is any byte that resides in a variable that wasn't assigned in some well-defined way.  The character `A` can be a garbage character if it happens to appear in (for example) a block of memory returned by `malloc` or an uninitialized `char` variable.

This is distinct from **unprintable characters** which are any character that does not have a well-defined representation when printed as characters.  For example, ASCII codes 0 - 31 and 127 (0 - 1F and **7F** hex) are control characters and therefore unprintable.  There are also multibyte characters for which a particular terminal may not know how to render them.

To get into your specific questions:

> Why can't the character (image) be copied?

As an unprintable character, its screen representation is not well defined.  So attempting to copy and paste it from a terminal will yield unexpected results.

> Do garbage characters have some pattern? Meaning that can you
>   predict for an empty string what character can come, for an empty
>   integer what will come, and so on.

The nature of garbage characters is that their contents are undefined.  Trying to predict what uninitialized data will contain is a futile effort.  The same piece of code compiled with two different compilers (or the same compiler with different optimization settings) can have completely different contents for any uninitialized data.

The standard doesn't say what values should go there, so implementations are free to handle it however they want.  They could chose to leave whatever values happen to be at those memory addresses, they could choose to write 0 to all addresses, they could choose to write the values 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. in sequence.  In other words, the contents are **undefined**.

> When a variable is declared, why does it have a garbage character
>   instead of being blank? Is there a specific reason of storing it with
>   a garbage character?

Global variables and static local variables are initialized with all bytes zero, which is what the standard dictates.  That is something that is done  easily at compile time.  Local variables on the other hand reside on the stack.  So their values are whatever happens to be on the stack at the time the function is called.

Here's an interesting example:

```
void f1()
{
    char str[10];
    strcpy(str, "hello");
}

int main()
{
    f1();
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what a particular implementation *might* do:

The first time `f1` is called, the local variable `str` is uninitialized. Then `strcpy` is called which copies in the string "hello".  This takes up the first 6 bytes of the variable (5 for the string and 1 for the null terminator).  The remaining 4 bytes are still garbage.  When this functions returns, the memory that the variable `str` resided at is free to be used for some other purpose.

Now `f1` gets called again immediately after the first call.  Since no other function was called, the stack for this invocation of `f1` happens to sit at the exact same place as the last invocation.  So if you were to examine `str` at this time, you would find it contains `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, and a null byte (i.e. the string "hello") for the first 6 bytes.  But, this string is **garbage**.  It wasn't specifically stored there.  If some other function was called before calling `f1` a second time, most likely those values would *not* be there.

Again, *garbage* means the contents are undefined.  The compiler doesn't explicitly put "garbage" (or unprintable characters) in variables.

> For a string which is not null-terminated, will the same garbage
>   character be printed on every OS? If yes, which one?

Here's one of those places you're confusing *garbage* and *unprintable*.  In your specific case, the garbage character happens to be unprintable, but it doesn't have to be.  Here's another example:

```
void f3()
{
    char str1[5], str2[5];

    strcpy(str1, "hello");
    strcpy(str2, "test");
    printf("str1=%s\n", str1);
}
```

Let's suppose the compiler decides to place `str2` immediately after `str1` in memory (although it doesn't have to).  The first call to `strcpy` will write the string "hello" into `str1`, but this variable doesn't have enough room the the null terminating byte.  So it gets written to the next byte in memory, which happens to be the first byte of `str2`.  Then when the next call to `strcpy` runs, it puts the string "test" in `str2` but in doing so it overwrites the null terminating byte put there when `str1` was written to.

Then when `printf` gets called, you'll get this as output:

```
str1=hellotest
```

When printing `str1`, `printf` looks for the null terminator, but there isn't one inside of `str1`.  So it keeps reading until it does.  In this case there happens to be another string right after it, so it prints that as well until it finds the null terminator that was properly stored in that string.

But again, this behavior is **undefined**.  A seemingly minor change in this function could result in `str2` appearing in memory first.  The compiler is free to do as it wishes in the regard, so there's no way to predict what will happen.

> Are there the same garbage characters on every OS? Or are they
>   different?

I believe you're actually referring to *unprintable* characters in this case.  This really depends on the character set of the OS and/or terminal in question.  For example, Chinese characters are represented with multiple bytes.  If your terminal can't print Chinese characters, you'll see some type of code similar to what you saw for each of the bytes.  But if it can, it will display it in a well-defined manner.

> Is there a way to print these characters on the stdout buffer in C /
>   C++?

Not as characters.  You can however print out their numerical representations.  For example:

```
void f4()
{
    char c;
    printf("c=%02hhX\n", (unsigned char)c);
}
```

The contents of `c` are undefined, but the above will print whatever value happens to be there in hexadecimal format.

> If you see carefully in the character (image),
>   there are some characters and numbers in it. Do they represent
>   something?

Some terminals will display unprintable characters by printing a box containing the [Unicode codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) of the character so the reader can know what it is.

Unicode is a standard for text where each character is assigned a numerical *code point*.  Besides the typical set of characters in the ASCII range, Unicode also defines other characters, such as accented letters, other alphabets like Greek, Hebrew, Cyrillic, Chinese, and Japanese, as well as various symbols.  Because there are thousands of characters defined by Unicode, multiple bytes are needed to represent them.  The most common encoding for Unicode is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which allows regular ASCII characters to be encoded with one byte, and other characters to be encoded with two or more bytes as needed.

In this case, the codepoint in question is 007F.  This is the DELETE control character, which is typically generated when the Delete key is pressed.  Since this is a control character, your terminal is displaying it as a box with the Unicode point for the character instead of attempting to "print" it.

> Is there a list of garbage characters which can be printed in C /
>   C++?

Again, assuming you really mean *unprintable characters* here, that has more to do with the terminal that's displaying the characters that with the language.  Generally, control characters are unprintable, while certain multibyte characters may or may not display properly depending on the font / character set of the terminal.

Comment: This is good, but in your `f3` function, you type `printf("str1=%s\n");` without passing any second argument, and `hellotest` gets printed as per you? I think this is a typo.

Comment: I also could not understand the second last question: "If you see carefully in the character (image), there are some characters and numbers in it. Do they represent something?". What is _Unicode Codepoint_? Also, what is _DELETE control character_?

Comment: @AshishAhuja The missing parameter was a typo.  `str1` should have been passed in.  This has been fixed.  I also added a description of Unicode as well as links to more detailed info, and a description of the DELETE character.

Comment: That is more clear. But I still have a question. You have written that garbage characters is undefined, that means that each time I run it the output can be different. Although, whenever I run it, I get the same output. So do you mean that with some kind of program which is printing garbage characters, the garbage characters will always be the same for that program, or is it just luck?

Comment: @AshishAhuja For a given compiled program and a given set of input, the garbage characters in local variables will typically be the same, since the program is behaving exactly the same way each time.  But if you change what you feed to the program, or if you simply add one or two lines of code that don't appear to do anything, this can change what this garbage data is.  And for dynamically allocated memory, it's highly likely to be different each time.

Comment: ^^ Does that mean adding an empty `printf` like `printf ("");` can change the garbage character printed? If yes, how?

Comment: @AshishAhuja Yes it can.  Calling a function modifies the stack, which is where local variables live.  When the call to `printf` returns, anything that was on the stack such as the parameters passed to `printf` and whatever local variables `printf` used would likely still be in those memory locations.  So whatever function gets called next will contain whatever those values were.

Comment: That clears everything. I'll award the bounty when the timer gets over. It's showing that I can award it in 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function returns incorrect value of `len`. Let's assume that `lim` is equal to `2`.

In this case in the loop there will be written nothing in the array due to the condition

```
if (len < (lim -2))
```

However after the first iteration of the loop `len` will be increased.

```
for (len = 0; (c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++len)
                                                    ^^^^^
```

In the second iteration again there will be written nothing in the array diue to the same condition

```
if (len < (lim -2))
```

but `len` will be increased.

```
for (len = 0; (c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++len)
                                                    ^^^^^
```

Thus nothing will be written in the array but len will be increased until for example the new line character will be encountered.

So the function is invalid. Moreover it is supposed that the function will append the read string with the terminating zero. But this is not done in the function. So you may not output the character array as a string.

The function can be written the following way

```
int scanline( char str [], int lim )
{
    int len = 0;
    int c;    

    while ( len < lim - 1 && ( c = getchar () ) != EOF && c != '\n' ) 
    {
        str[len++] = c;
    }

    if ( len < lim - 1 && c == '\n' ) str[len++] = c;

    if ( len < lim ) str[len++] = '\0';

    return len;
}
```