# Initialized values of array of pointers in a struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, initialization

Let's say I defined a struct that had an array of pointers to objects inside it, like so:

```
struct node {
    node *arr[10];
};
```

Then, I initialize an instance of the struct on the heap and check the contents of its array of pointers.

```
node *curr = new node;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if (curr->arr[i] == nullptr) std::cout << "null" << std::endl; 
} // this would print "null" 10 times in my tests in online IDEs and on QTCreator's C++ environment.
```

However, why do I see that each of the elements of the array is a nullptr? Shouldn't it be a garbage value? Is this default behavior for all structs with arrays of pointers?

I thought they should just be garbage pointers, not all nullptrs. Any tips on how to think about initialization of the `node` instance would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: "Garbage" really means "indeterminate" - they might, by chance, happen to be null pointers.  (Indeed many OSes zero out memory when first providing it to a process, so *if* you are getting fresh memory from the OS, instead of memory reused from a previous `delete`, you are *more likely* to see zeros.  Never any guarantees!)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666894/garbage-characters-in-c/35709149#35709149 explains it pretty well - for characters, not pointers, but the principle is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the memory allocator's status, it's a black box for programmers . For your code snippet, we can check the corresponding assembly:

```
f():                                  # @f()
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     edi, 80
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rax
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], 0
```

Only the operator new is called, since the struct is a plain old data type, we don't have a non-trivial constructor called here, the memory we allocated is untouched.

If we change the code slightly by inserting a memory allocation and deallocation with exactly same size with your struct:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
const size_t n = 10;
struct node {
  node *arr[n];
};

void f() {
  {
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> up(new char[sizeof(node)]);
    memset(up.get(), 0xff, sizeof(node));
  }

  node *curr = new node;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (curr->arr[i] != nullptr) std::cout << "not null" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

We get garbage values now, this is because that we have allocated a memory block with the size `sizeof(node)`, and fill it with value then deallocate it immediately.

For modern memory allocators, they tend to retain a memory pool for different size ranges to boost the performance by avoiding too frequent system call (You may reference the design for [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html), the one in libc is similar but much simpler). In my code, we allocated a memory block with the size `sizeof(node)` and deallocate it, the memory will be held by the allocator. Then we allocate a node with `node *curr = new node;`, it's likely that we will get the same address returned by the previous allocation. So we get the `expected` garbage value now, it will be a different case for complex programs with multiple threads, we will ignore the complex scenario here.

To initialize variable in c++ is a good habit and can avoid many related bugs, I suggest always do it.

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v69EYWbYz).